# Toggle background on an off in a div by clickin on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to find a JavaScript/jQuery that makes it possible to toggle the background on and off on multiple `div`s.

I'm creating a website with a menu where I want to be able to highlight dishes by clicking on them. Also I want it to work on phone, tablet and browser.

```css
.full-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu-wrapper {
    height: 2em;
    width: 24em;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-wrapper">
    <div class="menu-wrapper">Click and toggle background between red and white</div>
        <div class="menu-wrapper">Click and toggle background between red and white</div>
            <div class="menu-wrapper">Click and toggle background between red and white</div>
                <div class="menu-wrapper">Click and toggle background between red and white</div>
                    <div class="menu-wrapper">Click and toggle background between red and white</div>
                        <div class="menu-wrapper">Click and toggle background between red and white</div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to click to toggle background on and off using simple JavaScript.

Also I need to be able to toggle background on multiple `div`s, both on browser, tablet and on phone.

I've been trying some scripts and modifying things that I've found, but since I lack the knowledge, I need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some CSS:

```
.bg-red {
  background:red;
}
```

Some JavaScript

```
$('.menu-wrapper').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('bg-red');
});
```

And you get this

```js
$('.menu-wrapper').on('click', function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('bg-red');
});
```

```css
.full-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu-wrapper {
    height: 2em;
    width: 24em;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.bg-red {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full-wrapper">
    <div class="menu-wrapper">Click and toggle background between red and white</div>
        <div class="menu-wrapper">Click and toggle background between red and white</div>
            <div class="menu-wrapper">Click and toggle background between red and white</div>
                <div class="menu-wrapper">Click and toggle background between red and white</div>
                    <div class="menu-wrapper">Click and toggle background between red and white</div>
                        <div class="menu-wrapper">Click and toggle background between red and white</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.menu-wrapper').on('click touchstart', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('bg-red');
});
```

for working in mobile devices